# Barcode scanning and printing AX 2012 | SSRS 2012

Tags: reporting-services, barcode, axapta, barcode-scanner, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a client's requirement to integrate barcode scanner and printer with AX.

I'm using code39 barcode type, and have stored encoded string (fomrat: *itemId%batchId*) in relevant table in a field with EDT BarcodeStr. I used this field with font  **BC C39 3 to 1 HD** and font-size 36pt in a report text box control and it worked fine. I scanned it and it gave required string by scanning.

But now when i made the same report in another server, it doesn't scan properly (either give half value or doesn't give anything at all, as in scanner doesn't read the barcode).

I tried to change the font size, but in vain.

Please suggest some solution, am I missing something?

Comment: Encoded string should *never* be stored (except in temp table). Use `Barcode.barcodeStr()` to encode.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: You will have to determine whether your report is wrong or your scanner is dysfunctional.

Comment: I would speculate that maybe your barcode setup was changed in a parameter (unless you are using a different renderer like pdf vs direct to printer)